# Create Amazon Timestream database without physical name using AWS CDK v2

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, amazon-timestream

AWS has [best practices for CDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/best-practices.html) in place, which state that it's better to use *generated names* for resources instead of *physical* ones, see section "Use generated resource names, not physical names".

Consider the following `Construct`:

```
from aws_cdk import aws_timestream
from constructs import Construct

class MyConstruct(Construct):
    def __init__(self, scope, id_):
        super().__init__(scope, id_)
    
    my_database = aws_timestream.CfnDatabase(self, "MyTimestreamDatabase")
    my_table = aws_timestream.CfnTable(
        scope=self, 
        id="MyTimestreamTable",
        database_name=my_database.database_name,
        retention_properties={...}
    )
    my_table.add_depends_on(my_database)
```

Running `cdk synth` involving an instance of this class throws

> TypeError: type of argument database_name must be str; got NoneType instead

**Question: How do I create an Amazon Timestream database with AWS CDK v2 without assigning a physical name to it?**

Comment: Try passing `my_database.ref` instead.

Comment: Same error, printing `my_database.ref`gives `${Token[TOKEN.265]}` instead of `None`, though.

Comment: It still says "got NoneType instead"? It's expected that printing will output a token - the name will be generated by cloudformation during deployment, so you can't print it in your CDK code.

Comment: Yes: "TypeError: type of argument database_name must be str; got NoneType instead", exactly the same.

Comment: I'm assuming the indentation in the code is just a formatting error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing `ref` instead works, as it is never None, and it returns the database name. [Docs for reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-timestream-database.html#aws-resource-timestream-database-return-values).

Example code:

```py
from aws_cdk import aws_timestream
import aws_cdk as cdk
from constructs import Construct

class MyConstruct(Construct):
    def __init__(self, scope, id_):
        super().__init__(scope, id_)
    
        my_database = aws_timestream.CfnDatabase(self, "MyTimestreamDatabase")
        my_table = aws_timestream.CfnTable(
            self, 
            "MyTimestreamTable",
            database_name=my_database.ref,
        )
        

app = cdk.App()

stack = cdk.Stack(app, "stack")

MyConstruct(stack, "construct")

app.synth()
```

You don't need to declare an explicit dependency - CDK knows that the table depends on the database because you're passing one of the database's props to it.

I can confirm this synths correctly on my machine with CDK 2.37.1.

Comment: Now I can also confirm that it also works on my machine with 2.37.1. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Did you manage to figure out why it wasn't working?

Comment: Call me stupid: In fact, I create another table in my code, right after the first one and within the same database, and I only changed `database_name` to `ref` for the first table; so the error was probably from the second table...

Comment: Ah, happens. I'm glad it works now.